# How to merge properties in SOPAUI

Tags: soapui

I'm new to SOAPUI. 
What I'm trying to do is to use one property and based on its value set number of other properties.

Ex.
let say I have following properties:

**ENV**=TEST

**TESTUsername**=testuser@mcompany.com

**TESTPassword**=12345

**TESTSite**=http://test.company.com

**PRODUserName**=realuser@company.com

**PRODPassword**=54321

**PRODSite**=http://www.company.com

now if I assign TEST value to ENV I would like to somewhere in SOAPUI assign all properties that start with TEST to adequate properties ex. **varUsername**, **varPassword** and **varSite**. If I assign PROD to ENV property all properties that start with PROD to be assigned to those properties.

Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there is no possibility in soapUI doing this out-of-the-box. I guess you will need to use a Groovy script which performs this task. Providing the properties are located on project level, the following Groovy code might solve your problem.

```
def TEST_PREFIX = "TEST"
def PROD_PREFIX = "PROD"
def USERNAME_SUFFIX = "Username"
def PASSWORD_SUFFIX = "Password"

def propertyLevel = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
def env = context.expand( '${#Project#ENV}' )

if (env == TEST_PREFIX) {
    propertyLevel.setPropertyValue(TEST_PREFIX + USERNAME_SUFFIX, "testusername@mycompany.com")
    propertyLevel.setPropertyValue(TEST_PREFIX + PASSWORD_SUFFIX, "testPassword")
} else if (env == PROD_PREFIX) {
    propertyLevel.setPropertyValue(PROD_PREFIX + USERNAME_SUFFIX, "produsername@mycompany.com")
    propertyLevel.setPropertyValue(PROD_PREFIX + PASSWORD_SUFFIX, "prodPassword")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you're looking for is Environment handling, see the tutorial here:

http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-Projects/environment-handling-in-soapui.html

You can set up a 'TEST' environment and a 'PROD' environment and define values for your Username/Password/Site variables in each.

Comment: appears to not be there in soapui 5.2.0?